# Are these two words masculine or feminine?

Tags: перевод

I ran into two words that ends with the same letter in plural. My book sometimes marks if a word is masculine or feminine sometimes they just omit it. Can you please help out?

рубль     (M or F)

трамвай   (M or F)

Comment: Could you please clarify what M and F mean in your book?

Answer (score 3):

Both are masculine.

Any online dictionary (wiktionary.org, for instance) should be able to tell you most of what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the dictionary reference. Many times it takes a lot of time to find something that is reliable on the interweb.

Comment: You can't believe everything written on WIki since it's written by users, but most of it peer-reviewed and relatively reliable.  Wiktionary is one place that is almost free of bias, unlike Wikipedia, for instance.

Comment: I highly appreciate the dictionary. It has a very nice audio section with very clean audio clip. It beats the stuff I have been forced to use so far with light years. The book we are using is crap and the teacher we have I wonder some times how she got her job. Not only, does she rip off material from others but also if you steal something and claim as your material you might want to check the spelling before publishing it. About Wiki. I have actually changed content and got it approved by "peers" and used the false information as reference for PR purposes.